# Baseball - Where can i find the names of all pitchers in game? (not only starting pitchers)

Tags: baseball

Baseball - Where can i find the names of  all pitchers in game? (not only starting pitchers)

next games or games already played

Comment: Any team's 25 man roster is available - is that what you're after?

Comment: Where to find a team list depends on the competition and the team itself. Of the hundreds that exist, you want all of them? VTC *too broad*.

Comment: Baseball-reference.com has stats for all players. You can adjust for position.

Answer (score 1):

The MLB or ESPN websites have a website devoted to each team in MLB. Each teams page has a roster section which lists the teams 25 man roster broken down by position.  The iPhone and other smart phones app "At Bat" has this information too on each teams web page.  Bill James' web site has a list of all pitchers but in a ranked order.